# Is it safe to leave a Pi Zero W on 24/7?

Tags: pi-zero-w

I have a slightly annoying habit to turn off electronic devices whenever possible, but I would like to use the Pi Zero W as a lightweight web server for personal use. Any advice to get over this habit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to leave any Raspberry Pi on 24/7, including the Pi Zero W.  "Safe" in that case means no damage to the Pi.  For the environment to be safe, *e.g.* not burning down your house, the Pi should be in an insulating case and the power supply should be of high quality.  (I doubt you could really start a fire by short-circuiting the power supply, but you get the idea.)

Finally, there's software safety.  My home gets a power "blip" every month or so and a failure of minutes or longer every couple of years.  Sudden removal of power can corrupt the microSD card, so have a backup. If the service provided by the Pi is critical, consider an uninterruptible power supply.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some tips to help achieving a longer lifetime of your Pi:

- Use a well suitable PSU (really recommending the Original Raspberry Pi Power supply here)
- Place the Pi in a well ventilated area, a fan should not be necessary
- Secure it sufficiently (e.g. turning off passwort authentication and using a SSH key instead) so that it is harder to hack
- If the power drops out often, I suggest you to use a powerbank or a UPS board

Then it should be safe to leave it on all the time, but you might want to get a USB-to-Ethernet adapter or an ethernet HAT/shield for faster and more reliable network access.